# Are "thank you" or similar notes allowed in questions and answers?

Tags: discussion

Are "thank you" or similar notes allowed in questions and answers?

I believe that they are banned on some other engineering forums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not banned, but frowned upon.

If you see these, please edit the question, remove the signatures and thanks.

Then explain in the note, that they can thank by up voting and accepting answers.

For signatures, there is one already provided under each post.

We can't punish new members for being polite, like required on traditional forums. This is a question-and-answer site. The format is different, and we just need to educate users.

Stack Overflow's etiquette has matured over time. [Please refer to this FAQ but](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) don't consider it as LAW, that the worst kind of moderating that puts of new users and leaves them with a bad taste of the site. I am sure Joel Spolsky didn't design this to do that to people who are looking for answers.

Comment: **[This sentiment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/212479)** from Stack Exchange co-founder Jeff Atwood sums up just how frowned upon salutations ("Hi!") are.  What you've said in the last paragraph I think does not mesh well with the suggestion to "please edit...remove".  Of course it isn't something that's going to get you in trouble, but if someone else has to clean it up, then please don't do it in the first place and *do* regard that as a rule.  I admit to appending "Thx" to a comment on occasion O_O

Comment: Somebody had to clean up after me when I started.... then I cleaned up for a while .. you cleaned up .. now Chetan should be cleaning up :) (I still clean up on many exchanges, especially grammar!) This is the pure ideology that Joel envisaged, that the community drives and polices the sites with minimal "paid employee moderation" - More and more people appreciate how much better Q&A but they have to learn, and learning is painful for some people. `Thx 4 u t!me =]`